# How i can extend the Codeigniter library in Pyrocms

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, pyrocms

I want to add some more library and helpers file into Pyrocms which is based on codeigniter.Actually i have to add facebook connect and found some good working examples of facebook connect so now i want to implement these codeingiter libraries and other files in Pyrocms.Let let me know where to put these libraries. Your help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since version 1.3.0 `addons/default/libraries` 
or `addons/shared_addons/libraries` for the pro version.  (This bit will help on the where to put stuff topic...
http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/1.3/manuals/developers/understanding-the-addons-directory )

Then load the lib in your controller, etc as such `$this->load->library('cool_facebook_connect_lib');`
And, depending on your version you may have to change around a couple lines in MY_loader for it to work, http://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/18087

Comment: Thanks for the reply....Its really helpful for me....but have you work on facebook connect in Pyrocms/Codeigntier...:)

Comment: No, its on my short list. Have you looked at Phil's [Social Integration](http://www.pyrocms.com/store/details/social_integration) module?  Check out the video under _Demo_.

Comment: Ohkk........Thanks ....Now i am writing my own code..Thanks for your reply.....:)